# How do I resolve these grep errors in an AppleScript?

Tags: regex, grep, applescript

I am having trouble translating a working shell script regex to AppleScript. What do I need to change on the AppleScript side? (Thanks to those who helped in https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=205905#p205905)

Here is the working shell script regex

```
john@mac ~ % ExtractedNoteContents="Test Project                 
- [ ] Potential Task 1
- [ ] <0001f7e2> Potential Task 2 (with some comment; additions)

<0001f7e2> Potential Task 3
More text"
john@mac ~ % echo $ExtractedNoteContents | grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'
 Potential Task 2 (with some comment; additions)
 Potential Task 3
```

Here is the failing AppleScript regex

```
set ExtractedNoteContents to "Test Project
- [ ] Potential Task 1
- [ ]  Potential Task 2 (with some comment; additions)

 Potential Task 3
More text"
do shell script "echo " & ExtractedNoteContents & " | grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'"
```

Here is the error I get:

```
sh: line 1: -: command not found
sh: -c: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 2: `- [ ]  Potential Task 2 (with some comment; additions)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `quoted form` when passing a *variable* to a `do shell script` *command*.

Change:

```
do shell script "echo " & ExtractedNoteContents & " | grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'"
```

To:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of ExtractedNoteContents & " | grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'"
```

Or:

```
do shell script "echo " & ExtractedNoteContents's quoted form & " | grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'"
```

My preferred method is, e.g.:

```
do shell script "grep -o '<0001f7e2>.*'<<<" & ExtractedNoteContents's quoted form
```

I prefer to use *Here strings*  instead of `echo |` and I personally find it more readable.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>

Comment: Thank you for demonstrating the multiple methods possible in using "quoted form".

Comment: I get a different error, now, with all of the methods:
error "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1

Comment: @John, The error `error "The command exited with a non-zero status." number 1` is because `grep` didn't find a match. This actually has nothing to do with the original issue, which was really only about not quoting what was passed to the _shell_. You need to employ proper _error handling_ when writing _code_.  You can always post a different question since the answer I posted already address the original issue.

Comment: @John, Also have a look at the note I added to the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I realized it was a different issue, but I did stumble upon the solution, myself. I have to use the actual emoji with the grep and then it returns the results I expect.